# Jquery: Deleting the child node of even rows of the table

Tags: jquery

I  have the below Jquery code. For the first and third column of the table , is there anyway to delete the child node of even rows of the table?

```
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type = "checkbox" name = "vehicle"> </td>
      <td>BBB</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td> <input type = "checkbox" name = "vehicle"> </td>
      <td>BBB</td>   
    </tr>     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#table1 > tr:odd")               
});
```

I am looking for a way to delete all the above checkbox node 
present in the Odd rows of first column.

Through the above Jquery , I can select all the odd rows, but 
Is there any way to modify it to delete all the checkbox node 
from those selected odd rows of first column.

Comment: You forgot to include the code

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle link :  http://jsfiddle.net/Raj151515/th61vruq/

Comment: Please refer this updated JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Raj151515/th61vruq/1/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `>` in your initial selector because there's a tbody between them, then use the below code to find the checkbox and remove them.

```
$('#table1 tr:odd').find('input[type="checkbox"]').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/th61vruq/2/